# "Unquote"/parse bash argument string in python

Tags: python, bash, escaping

I have a python script that takes its input from the command line arguments. For example:

```
./myscript.py first_item second\ item "third item"
```

I can output separate items and escape spaces and special characters using [`pipes.quote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html).

```
print " ".join(map(pipes.quote, outputItems))
```

*Is there any existing "`unquote`" interface that will parse a bash argument string, keeping escaped spaces and quoted strings intact?*

Something that would allow the same python script to handle this:

```
echo 'first_item second\ item "third item"' | ./myscript.py
```

Comment: Note that this is what `xargs` did, and it turned out to be a horrible design decision that people still suffer from 30 years later. It's generally agreed that `\0` terminated strings, or at the very least `\n` terminated, is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`shlex.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
s = 'first_item second\ item "third item"'

import shlex

shlex.split(s)
Out[3]: ['first_item', 'second item', 'third item']
```